# Using ResponseEntity<String> for Spring controller errors

Tags: kotlin, spring-mvc, swagger

My Spring application uses `arrow.core.Either` for error handling. Service layer methods have return types like this:

```kotlin
fun foo(): Either<MyCustomError, MyResult>
```

`MyCustomError` always contains an HTTP status code to use and an error message to put in the response body. This means a controller method can't return `ResponseEntity<MyResult>`, because it can also be `ResponseEntity<String>`:

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/foo")
fun foo(): ResponseEntity<*> = service.foo()
    .fold(
        { ResponseEntity.status(it.status).body(it.message) }, // produces ResponseEntity<MyResult>
        { ResponseEntity.ok(it) }, // produces ResponseEntity<String>
    )
```

Which is troublesome when Swagger tries to determine response models. I end up with:

[image]

Am I missing something here? Is there a way around this limitation?

Comment: If you worked with exceptions, you could write `@ExceptionHandler` methods that return a `ResponseEntity<String>`, and have your regular controller methods return `ResponseEntity<MyResult>`